# Loop is breaking my theme. How can I fix?

Tags: theme-development, loop

When my theme tries to load home.php, archive.php or any page that uses the loop, the page will stop loading exactly at the point the loop should begin, even the wpadmin bar won't load.

If I navigate to a category page that has no content to show (as no posts are labelled as that category) the page will load perfectly well with the wpadmin bar, and show a 404 where the content would be. (Expected behavior)

Anyone know why this would happen?

Here is my loop:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">

 <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'posts'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="pagination">

      <?php echo paginate_links( array(
        'prev_text' => 'Back',
        'next_text' => 'Next',
        'end_size' => '0',
        'mid_size' => '1'
      ) ); ?>

    </div>

</div><!--primary-->
```

The main tag is closed in the footer.

Here is my content-posts.php code (you might not need to look at this but posting here just in case):

```
<article id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>" <?php  post_class(); ?>>

<header class="entry-header">

    <div class="article-excerpt">

        <!-- The following links the thumbnail image to the atricle, if there is a thumbnail -->
        <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
            title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="byline"> <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/byline' ); ?></div>
        <?php   the_title( '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <div class="excerpt-date"><?php the_date( '','// ','', ) ?></div>
    </div>

    <hr class="excerpt-hrtop">

</header>

<div class="entry-content">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_content( '<div class="excerpt-readmore">READ MORE</div>' ); ?>
    </a>

</div>

<hr class="excerpt-hrbottom">
```

I have tried using query_posts before the loop as was advised in answers to other questions and that didn't work.

I use DesktopServer to work offline and the website works great.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the memory limit and time out settings?

Comment: One of your final statements is confusing me.  The website works great?  Is that locally only and the problem is with the version hosted via a webhosting company?

Comment: That is correct. Locally it works as expected. The problem is with a version hosted by Bluehost.

Comment: It's probably not the cause of your issue, but you appear to be closing the primary div before the main tag is closed, which is the incorrect order based on the order that you're opening them.

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down to this line in my content-posts.php file: **<div class="excerpt-date"><?php the_date( '','// ','', ) ?></div>**. I've removed the class (to eliminate css) and it still breaks the site. So I'm using **the_date** incorrectly. Will leave answer when I find out what it is exactly.

Comment: Hey Cathal, there should be a semicolon at then end of that function. Could possibly be that and different php error settings on bluehost to your local setup. Might not be the cause, but worth eliminating the possibility.